# Is there a name for a "rigid" sheaf?

Tags: terminology, sheaf-theory

Is there a name for the property of a sheaf $\mathcal F$ such that the restriction maps $\mathcal F(V) \to \mathcal F(U)$ are injective when $V$ is a connected open and $U$ is a nonempty open?

In other words, this is a sheaf which satisfies the "[identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)" of complex analysis (taking for $\mathcal F$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions).

Many sheaves in algebraic geometry satisfy this property, but I've never heard a name for it. Perhaps a "rigid" sheaf, in contrast to a "flasque" sheaf? (This "identity theorem" property seems to be the one which gave [rigid analytic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_analytic_space) its name, but I have never seen the words "rigid sheaf" written down.)

Thank you.

Comment: [x-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165448/is-there-a-name-for-a-rigid-sheaf) to MO.